# Vertically Center Font Awesome Icon in Navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

If I have a navbar like so:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <i class="fa fa-plane fa-3x navbar-text" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-bottom: 1.5%;"></i><strong class="navbar-brand">Test Site</strong>
        </div>
  </div>
  </nav>
```

The plane isn't centered in the navbar, let alone centered against the text it is beside.  I have tried inline margins but that doesn't seem to move it.

How can this be done?

Here is a [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/oQ2fGQ5oiA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adjusting the y-axis margins just for the font..

```
  .fa.navbar-text {
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
   }
```

http://www.bootply.com/cIt2OwPoaG

Comment: I'm sorry if my question was misleading, but I am not looking to put the icon in the center of my navbar, rather just move it up off of the bottom of the navbar.. that's what I meant by center.

Comment: Yeah, it is misleading as the title says "Center Font Awesome Icon in Navbar". Do you mean vertically center, and not horizontal center?